# Dynamically add html depending on dynamically generated html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dynamic

I'm currently working on a project for which I have to develop a WordPress plugin allowing to manipulate tables in databases. My work is based on this plugin, which I'm improving and editing to match the requirements of my company : https://wordpress.org/plugins/create-db-tables/

My problem however doesn't concern MySQL, but html, Php and jQuery (especially jQuery, which I'm not familiar with, at all). It's about dynamically generating a form, itself depending on a dynamically generated form (yeah...).

With the following code, the plugin user is able to dynamically add rows to the table he's creating. I would like him to be able to add "sub-rows" (I know how to handle it server-side, my problem here is only the interface), like that :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FfbW.png

When the user clicks "Add subrows", a zone appears where he can fill out a form, etc. It works perfectly (at least the interface) for the first row, but after that, whenever I click another "Add subrows" button, nothing happens.

I'd appreciate very much if someone could take time to tell me where I'm doing something wrong. Thank you so much ! :)

Here is my code :
(the first jQuery script seemingly works, I'm not the one who developed it. I duplicated it and tried to adapt the second one to my "sub-row" requirement)

```
<form id="create-table" method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>">

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_table">

        <fieldset class="table-fieldset">
            <label id="table-name">Table Name:</label> <br />
            <span style="position: relative; top: 2px;"><?php echo "Choose prefix (by default wp_ ) : " ?></span><input type="text" class="prefix-name" name="prefix_name" size="4" id="prefix-name"><br />
            <span style="position: relative; top: 2px;"><?php echo "Choose table name :" ?></span><input type="text" class="table-name" name="table_name" size="30" id="table-name">
            <span>(Alphanumeric only, no special characters.)</span> <br/> <br/>
            <span><font color="blue"><strong>Will this table be used for user authentication ? </strong></font></span><input type="checkbox" class="is-user-auth" name="is_user_auth" id="is-user-auth"><br/>
            <span><strong>/!\ Only one table at a time can be used for user authentication : if a current table is used for this purpose, it won't be anymore.</strong></span><br/><br/>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="rows">
            <fieldset class="row-fieldset" id="row-fieldset" value="1"><label id="row-label">Row:</label><input type="text" class="name-input" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" size="20"><input type="text" class="type-input" name="type[]" placeholder="Type [Ex: bigint(20)]" size="20"><span id="null-label">Null</span><input type="checkbox" class="null-input" name="null[]"><input type="text" class="default-input" name="default[]" placeholder="Default Value" size="20"><span id="unique-label">Unique</span><input type="checkbox" class="unique-input" name="unique[]"><button type="button" class="row-dynamic" style="background-color: #E3F6CE">Add subrows</button><div id="subrows1" value="1"></div></fieldset>
        </div>

        <div id="add-row">
            <button type="button" class="add-row button-secondary">Add Row</button>
        </div>

        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" id="subrowitems" name="subrowitems" value="101" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="button button-primary button-large">Create Table</button>
        </fieldset>

    </form>

    <!-- Script to add rows -->
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('.add-row').click(function () {
                $('#items').val(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
                var val_2=$('#items').attr('value');
                var subrow_name = 'subrows'+val_2;
                var rowHTML = '<fieldset class="row-fieldset" id="row-fieldset" value=\"'+val_2+'\"><label id="row-label">Row:</label><input type="text" class="name-input" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" size="20"><input type="text" class="type-input" name="type[]" placeholder="Type [Ex: bigint(20)]" size="20"><span id="null-label">Null</span><input type="checkbox" class="null-input" name="null[]"><input type="text" class="default-input" name="default[]" placeholder="Default Value" size="20"><span id="unique-label">Unique</span><input type="checkbox" class="unique-input" name="unique[]"><button type="button" class="row-dynamic" style="background-color: #E3F6CE">Add subrows</button><div id=\"'+subrow_name+'\" value=' + val_2 + '></div></fieldset>';
                $('#rows').append(rowHTML);
            });
            $("input.name-input").on({
                keydown: function(e) {
                    if (e.which === 32)
                        return false;
                },
                change: function() {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
                }
            });
            $("input.table-name").on({
                keydown: function(e) {
                    if (e.which === 32)
                        return false;
                },
                change: function() {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Script to add subrows -->
    <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('.row-dynamic').click(function () {
                $('#subrowitems').val(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
                var val_3=$('#subrowitems').attr('value');
                var subrowHTML = '<fieldset class="subrow-fieldset" value=\"' +val_3+ '\"><label id="subrow-label">Subrow:</label><input type="text" class="subrow-name-input" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" size="20" style="background-color: #E3F6CE"><input type="text" class="subrow-type-input" name="type[]" placeholder="Type [Ex: bigint(20)]" size="20" style="background-color: #E3F6CE"><span id="subrow-null-label">Null</span><input type="checkbox" class="subrow-null-input" name="null[]" style="background-color: #E3F6CE"><input type="text" class="subrow-default-input" name="default[]" placeholder="Default Value" size="20" style="background-color: #E3F6CE"><span id="subrow-unique-label">Unique</span><input type="checkbox" class="subrow-unique-input" name="unique[]" style="background-color: #E3F6CE"></fieldset>';
                var subrow_val = '#subrows'+$('#row-fieldset').attr('value');
                $(subrow_val).append(subrowHTML);
            });
            $("input.subrow-name-input").on({
                keydown: function(e) {
                    if (e.which === 32)
                        return false;
                },
                change: function() {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
                }
            });
            $("input.table-name").on({
                keydown: function(e) {
                    if (e.which === 32)
                        return false;
                },
                change: function() {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some duplicated id's on your HTML sintax (e.g. `#row-fieldset`)

If you check your HTML code you initializes a `fieldset` tag with the row-fieldset `id`

```
<fieldset class="row-fieldset" id="row-fieldset" value="1">
```

and later you create a new one with the same `id`

```
var rowHTML = '<fieldset class="row-fieldset" id="row-fieldset" value=\"'+val_2+'\
```

So when JQuery tries to find the proper `id`, only find the first one.

I added to the <kbd>Add subrows</kbd> button a value for locate the correct row

Also you did not provide any jQuery version so I used 2.2.0

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epgeroy/y7fbks5u/3/) to see it running

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, your code works perfectly on my website (I use jQuery 2.2.3 but it is basically the same).
Now I understand my mistakes and I will try not to reiterate them.
Cheers !